# "I will go to the party *to* kiss her" vs. "I will go to the party *and* kiss her"

Tags: meaning, grammar, future-tense

"I will go to the party to kiss her."

"I will go to the party and kiss her."

Which one is more "proper one? I'm thinking second one is more formal but I'm not sure.

Comment: Which one do you mean?  In the first case "kissing her" is the only reason to attend the party.  In the second case you hope to accomplish two things -- attending the party and kissing her.

Answer (score 3):

The sentences have different meanings.

The first describes the [purpose](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/infinitive) of the going to the party. It could answer the question "Why are you going to the party?"

The second just describes two events. It is roughly equivalent to two sentences "I will go to the party. I will kiss her".

They are both standard English; they are equally formal.

Answer (score -1):

1, I will  go to the party to kiss her means I will go to the party only for this purpose ( kissing her ) and I don't  have any other purpose of going there.

2, I will go to the party and kiss her portrays an advice  from someone else.For example, someone informs you that your girlfriend is leaving  for Canada for two years and a party is to be held in her honor on next weekend so you had better go there and kiss her to end your tiny differences for ever. At this you reply, I will .....